# Como hacer que el clip-path se mueva con la imagen?

Tags: css, css3, svg

Tengo un problema al utilizar clip-path: el clip no acompaña a la figura, no se mueve con ella, sino que se queda pegado en una esquina. Entonces cuando trato de hacer el responsive se complica todo. 
Aquí agrego un ejemplo del código que estoy utilizando. La imagen del background termina en ángulo. Yo necesito que cuando se empequeñece la pantalla esa imagen continúe así. Pero se pierde el ángulo.
Alguien tiene alguna recomendación que me oriente?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #caja1{
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517880014665-8b84b2e26002?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f68dce4bbc5a44c6e499aec220423bd2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 90%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 90%);
        width: 100%;
        height: 900px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="caja1">
        fondo marino
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Olga y bienvenida a [es.so]. Sería genial que postees parte del código o más información para contextualizar tu pregunta. [Editala](/edit) siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción es poner un contenedor que le dé el tamaño al div con el clip, darle al div interno 100% ancho y alto, y a la imagen hacerla que haga un cover de todo el fondo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #caja-contenedor {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    #caja1 {
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517880014665-8b84b2e26002?ixlib=rb-0.3.5…jEyMDd9&s=f68dce4…&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60);
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 90%);
      clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 90%);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="caja-contenedor">
    <div id="caja1">
      fondo marino
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

- `#caja-contenedor` dicta el tamaño
- `#caja1` se adapta en clip y background

**edit**  agrego demo cambiando id por clases y un ejemplo de como limitar los anchos o altos del contenedor

```css
#caja-contenedor {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 640px;
  max-height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contenedor {
  position: relative;
}

.caja-bkg {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517880014665-8b84b2e26002?ixlib=rb-0.3.5…jEyMDd9&s=f68dce4…&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0%, 100% 70%, 0% 90%);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-20 {
  width: 20%;
}

.col-60 {
  width: 60%;
}

.unatabla {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div id="caja-contenedor" class="contenedor">
  <div class="caja-bkg">
    fondo marino
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row unatabla">
  <div class="col-20">primera columna</div>
  <div class="col-60 contenedor">
    <div class="caja-bkg">
      fondo marino 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-20">tercera columna bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto en el archivo de prueba. Estoy tratando de implementarlo en el archivo real, pero no me funciona, estoy tratando de buscar el error. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @OlgaL.V. ¿Te da algún error por consola?

Comment: el como aplicar el contenedor varia mucho según la estructura y estilos que ya tengas, te agrego una opcion el ejemplo a ver si te sirve

Comment: Tengo varios errores por consola, pero no se deben al cambio que me sugirió @alo Malbarez.

Comment: Ya me funciona perfecto! Tenía que agrandar los tamaños de la #caja- contenedor. Te agradezco mucho la explicación.

Comment: je justo estaba poniendo el ejemplo de como limitar o definir los altos/anchos del contenedor